# Editing and saving array through FileManager and PropertyListEncoder Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, encoding

Today was the day I **quit** saving `data` with `UserDefaults` and started using `FileManager` and `PropertyListEncoder` instead.

*I won't lie, I broke my code in the transition.*

The user creates an `array` that is used to fill a `tableView` and this array needs to be updated by the user, when he deletes a row or changes a value for instance.

My code is able to successfully create the array, display the cells and do the calculations at the correct indexPath to display correct data.

*The problems start there, here is what's wrong:*

**1.** When a cell is deleted and another one is created, the deleted one comes back along the new one (if you restarted the app after deleting the cell it wouldn't be there anymore).

**2.** `amount` is not updated (nor saved) to `cryptosArray`. It is `0` again when the app is re-launched.

Here is the code:

**Array creation:**

```
func createCryptoArray(_ addedCrypto: String) {

    if addedCrypto != "" {
        if addedCrypto == "Bitcoin BTC" {
            let crypto1 = Cryptos(name: "Bitcoin", code: "bitcoin", symbol: "BTC", placeholder: "BTC Amount", amount: "0.0")
            CryptoPickerViewController.cryptos.append(crypto1)
        }
        if addedCrypto == "Bitcoin Cash BCH" {
            let crypto2 = Cryptos(name: "Bitcoin Cash", code: "bitcoinCash", symbol: "BCH", placeholder: "BCH Amount", amount: "0.0")
            CryptoPickerViewController.cryptos.append(crypto2)
        }

        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("cryptosArray").appendingPathExtension("plist")
        let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
        let encodedArray = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(CryptoPickerViewController.cryptos)

        try? encodedArray?.write(to: archiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)
    }
}
```

**Array loading and TableView filling:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    tableView.delegate = self

    loadCryptoArray()

    tableView.reloadData()
}

func loadCryptoArray() {

    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("cryptosArray").appendingPathExtension("plist")
    let propertyListDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    if let retrievedArrayData = try? Data(contentsOf: archiveURL),
        let decodedArray = try?
            propertyListDecoder.decode(Array<Cryptos>.self, from: retrievedArrayData) {
        cryptosArray = decodedArray
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cryptosArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let crypto = cryptosArray[indexPath.row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! WalletTableViewCell
    cell.setCrypto(crypto: crypto)
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.amountTextField.delegate = self

    return cell
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 85
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        cryptosArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("cryptosArray").appendingPathExtension("plist")
        let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
        let encodedArray = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(cryptosArray)
        try? encodedArray?.write(to: archiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)

    }
}
```

**Value update and display:**

```
func cellAmountEntered(_ walletTableViewCell: WalletTableViewCell) {

    if walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text == "" {
        return
    }

    let str = walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    let dNumber = formatter.number(from: str!)
    let nDouble = dNumber!
    let eNumber = Double(truncating: nDouble)
    walletTableViewCell.amountLabel.text = String(format:"%.8f", eNumber)

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: walletTableViewCell)
    let crypto = cryptosArray[(indexPath?.row)!]

    crypto.amount = String(format:"%.8f", eNumber)

    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let archiveURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("cryptosArray").appendingPathExtension("plist")
    let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
    let encodedArray = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(cryptosArray)
    try? encodedArray?.write(to: archiveURL, options: .noFileProtection)

    print("amount", crypto.amount)

    walletTableViewCell.amountTextField.text = ""

    //updateWalletValueLabel()
}
```

I tried to keep the post as short as possible so please tell me if I forgot any important information.

Comment: "Today was the day I quit saving data with `UserDefaults` and started using `FileManager` and `PropertyListEncoder` instead." ........why?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka A few people with a lot of reputation score here told me not to use userDefaults to save data..

Comment: FileManager is not the place either, Use Core data with NSFetchedResultsController as data source for your table view.

Comment: CoreData is what I'd recommend as well.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka Any chance one of you guys could show me how to save my `arrays` to the `context` with CoreData instead of FileManager in **Array creation:** up in my code? That would be awesome and I think I could go on by myself from there